# Quarkus how to use javascript list string in template

Tags: javascript, html, quarkus

I want to include javascript list string in template at quarkus app.

I define ConfigProperty like this.

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "my_list_string")
lateinit var myListStrings: List<String>
```

And I use this at template like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myListString = {myListStrings};
  myJSFunc(myListString);
</script>
```

When I set `my_list_string=test`, output is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myListString = [test];
  myJSFunc(myListString);
</script>
```

The myJSFunc needs list string, so I want to get `['test']`
Also, I set `my_list_string="'test'"`, the output is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myListString = [&#39;test&#39;];
  myJSFunc(myListString);
</script>
```

If anyone know how to set JavaScript list string at quarkus app, please tell me about it.
Thank you.

Environment
Java 11
Quarkus 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The `@ConfigProperty` happens on the server side (in Java).
You'll need to expose a REST method to get it the value of that property on the client side (in JavaScript).

Something like

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "my_list_string")
lateinit var myListStrings: List<String>

@Path("/my_list_string")
String getMyListString() {
   return my_list_string;
}
```

And then retrieve that in your .js file, probably in the document is loaded event.